# how to cite a website without getting an "underfull hbox" warning?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, urls, elsarticle

I am trying to cite a website but I am getting this message

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 1939) in paragraph at lines 9--11
```

my citation is

```
@MISC{K&J,
author        = {k\&J magnetics},
year          = {2011},
title         = {The original K\&J magnet calculator},
howpublished  ={\url{https://www.kjmagnetics.com/calculator.asp}},
note = {Accessed 2020-2-30},
}
```

the packages I am using

```
\documentclass[5p,preprint]{elsarticle}

\journal{Energy}
\setcitestyle{square}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
%\usepackage[round, sort & compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=whatever}
```

Comment: Please tell us whether you load the `xurl` package. (Hint: You should.)

Comment: Maybe loading hyperref and deleting \url{...} from howpublished.

Comment: I updated the question and added the packages I am using. What is the xur1 and how can I use it?

Comment: Luis, what do you mean by deleting \url

Comment: @soooleh - Not `xur1` - `xurl`. Try loading it right before `hyperref`, by running `\usepackage{xurl}`.

Comment: @Mico - it worked, thank you so much

Comment: @LuisTurcio - How might removing `\url` from a URL string help?

Comment: @soooleh and @Mico, my comment was clearly sloppy, what I mean is that is shouldn't be (or at least I believe) an `\url` inside a field when there is a dedicated field named `url`

Comment: @LuisTurcio - Many thanks for providing this clarification. I've incorporated your suggestion to make use of the dedicated `url` field in the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions and observations:

- To avoid getting warning messages about either underfull or overfull lines because of URL strings, load the `xurl` package *before* loading `hyperref`.
- Since the `elsarticle-num` bibliography style recognizes a field called `url`, use it, i.e, replace `howpublished = {\url{https://www.kjmagnetics.com/calculator.asp}},` with `url = {https://www.kjmagnetics.com/calculator.asp},`.
- Encase the string `K\&J` in the `title` field in curly braces to keep it from getting lowercased by BibTeX.
- Change the `author` field from `{k\&J magnetics}` to `{{K\&J Magnetics}}` so that the author is recognized as a "corporate" author and is sorted under K, not M.
- With the `elsarticle` document class, it's better to specify `times` as a document class option than it is to load it as a package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[5p,preprint,times]{elsarticle}
\journal{Energy}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{testbib.bib}
@MISC{K&J,
author        = {{K\&J Magnetics}},
year          = {2011},
title         = {The Original {K\&J} Magnet Calculator},
xxhowpublished= {\url{https://www.kjmagnetics.com/calculator.asp}},
url           = {https://www.kjmagnetics.com/calculator.asp},
note          = {Accessed 2020-2-30},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} % information gleaned from an earlier posting
\setcitestyle{square}

\usepackage{graphicx,subfig,amsmath,array,booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\usepackage{xurl} % <-- new
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=whoever}

\begin{document}
\cite{K&J}
\bibliography{testbib}
\end{document}
```